# Google chrome deleting javascript events after opening or closing developer console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, metabase

I have an iframe embedded in a webpage. This iframe has a some `rect` elements inside an `svg` element. The following code is used to bind events to the `rect elements:

JS code:

```
$(() => {
  let bindEvents = () => {
    let targets = $('iframe').contents().find('rect');
      $.each(targets, (elm, i) => {
        $(targets[elm]).on('click', () => {
            alert('Hello, World!');
        });
      });
  }
  setTimeout(bindEvents, 10000);
});
```

On chrome 64 these events are getting deleted when developer console is opened. On chrome 65, these events won't get binded if developer console is not opened.These issue is happening in chrome on ubuntu. Chrome 58 and 61 has no issues in binding evnets.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Metabase Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css"         />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content-root">
        <iframe width="100%" height="500" id="total-sales-test" src="url-from-metabase"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The url or the iframe is from metabase. I'm not able to post the full url here since it is confidential.

Comment: Is your iframe on the same domain and not a different or subdomain or so?

Comment: Same domain. Not cross origin issue is there.

Comment: Please add details in your question how you populate your iframe, best would be an example snippet(the `<>` button) that demonstrates the issue you have.